# With GetStream, how to remove all "comment" and "like" activities when their target is deleted?

Tags: getstream-io

When a user posts something new, the activity `foreign_id` is 'Post:id'. When a user comments on a post, the activity `foreign_id` is 'Comment:id' and the `target` is 'Post:id'.

When a user deletes his post, it's easy to remove activities directly related to this post using `removeActivity()`, but how can you remove all activities related to the comments and likes of this post?

Using my app database, I can easily retrieve all these comments and likes, but it seems like there is no `removeActivities()` method to batch remove activities from feeds.

The only way to do it that I see is to call `removeActivity()` for every comments and likes retrieved in my DB, but this seems like a bad way to do it. If there are 2000 comments and 2000 likes on a post, we will need 4000 api requests to delete this post...

Answer (score -2):

The best way to do this is to change how you track foreign_id for related objects such as likes and comments. If you store the reference to the "parent" object in the foreign_id field, deletes will propagate correctly.

Eg.

Post activity -> foreign_id = "Post:ID"

Comment activity -> foreign_id = "Post:ID"

Then, if you want to delete the post activity and all related comments and likes you perform a delete by foreign_id (see docs: https://getstream.io/docs/#removing-activities)

Note that when you want to delete just one activity (eg. the comment or like to a post) you have to perform the delete using the activity ID and not the foreign_id (this is also explained in the docs).

Comment: I can see that this will work for comments and likes that belong directly to a post, but then how would we handle removing "like" or "reply" activities of a comment? When a user likes a comment, if we create a "like" activity with `foreign_id` = "Post:id", we won't be able to delete it when the comment is deleted, while if we use `foreign_id` = "Comment:id", we won't be able to delete when the post is deleted... How could we handle these nested situations efficiently?

Comment: I also realised that the `removeActivity()` function is only performed on one single feed. So if I use the technique you suggested and perform a delete by `foreign_id` on a post, only the comments and likes on this same `user_feed` will be deleted, so comments from other users will remain... is that right?

Comment: hey @rubz i'd be interested to hear how you resolved the second issue.. on deleting activities across multiple feeds.

Comment: @MartinVerdejo I couldn't manage to solve this. In the end, I decided to handle this situation in my app logic. Since it's not a frequent situation, what I did is that if a user clicks on a notification about a comment on a post that doesn't exist anymore, it will display a message telling him about it. Not ideal, I know, but best I could do using GetStream.